# Formal way of asking "When are you in Berlin?"

Tags: phrase-request, informal-language

The question "When are you in Berlin?" sounds, somehow, strange to me and informal. Is it OK to ask this way in a business environment or is there a better way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What do you mean to ask?

> *When are you in Berlin?*

This carries a little of the connotation that the person being questioned either has regularly scheduled visits to Berlin (response: *"Every April and May"*) or has a longer itinerary already planned out, in which Berlin is a stop. (response: *"After Holland and Zurich, but before Warsaw and Nagurskoye."*)

If you are asking someone who is going to Berlin as a one off event, and not in the context of a longer trip, either `When will you be in Berlin?` or `When are you going to Berlin?` are more common.     (AmE, West Coast)

Comment: *When are you in Berlin?* can quite naturally refer to a one-off event in the right context.

Answer (score 3):

*When will you be in Berlin?* is an alternative, but I see nothing wrong with *When are you in Berlin?* There is nothing informal about it.